# Error : Loop variable must be of type Id

Tags: apex, trigger, list, loop

Can anyone please tell me, what should I do to avoid this error.

> **Error** : Loop variable must be of type Id.

What I am trying to do is,From incident object list and task object list, I am finding out the task which are linked to incident and collecting those task in list of type Id.

[image: Place where I am getting error]

[image: Line number where there is an error]

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Below is the code which I have written. As you said to you use map here but for Id will it hold string type?   

    List<Id> t1=new List<Id>();
    for(Integer j=0;j<resolvedIncident.size();j++)
    {
        for(Integer k=0;k<task.size();k++)
        {
            if(resolvedIncident.get(j).Id==task.get(k).BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c)
            {

                t1.add(task.get(k).BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c);               
                count=t1.size();                    
            }                
        }

        List<BMCServiceDesk__Task__c> T = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Task__c>();
        for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c updateTask : t1) // @ this line error 
        {
            updateTask.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c = closedStatusID.id;
            T.add(updateTask);

        }
```

Please suggest for the same.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For iterating through `for` loop, you must have a `List/Set` type variable.

Since you've `Id` in t1 then better use `for` loop as below:

```
// Initialize a list of task which needs to be updated
List<BMCServiceDesk__Task__c> lstUpdateTask = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Task__c> ();
for(Integer j=0;j<resolvedIncident.size();j++)
{
    for(Integer k=0;k<task.size();k++)
    {
        if(resolvedIncident.get(j).Id==task.get(k).BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c)
        {
            // add matched task into the list which needs to be updated.
            lstUpdateTask.add(task.get(k));                  
        }                
    }
}   

// Now we've list of Task which needs to be updated, simply run a for loop on it
for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c updateTask : lstUpdateTask) {
    updateTask.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c = closedStatusID.id;
} 

// Once all values are updated, simply update it.
if(lstUpdateTask.size () > 0)
    update lstUpdateTask;
```

Comment: Actually this t1 is a list created above which stores task Id. So, I have written t1 here. How can I replace T with t1?  As t1 holds task Id whose status I want to set to closed.

Comment: @EmmaWatson Updated the answer. And it would be better to post a code instead of a snapshot.

Comment: How will this update task object status then, if I wrote for(Id taskId: t1){// code block} Because list is of type Id and I want these task Id to be updated in task object status. Please suggest for the same.

Comment: @EmmaWatson In that case you need to refine your logic using `Map` something like which I posted in my answer.

Comment: Can anyone please update me on this???

Comment: @EmmaWatson Updated the answer, Though the code is not tested but it will give you rough idea, how your approach should be. Read comments to get better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the loop is that when we are iterating using the below code

```
for(BMCServiceDesk__Task__c updateTask : t1) // @ this line error
```

The system is expecting the the variable `t1` should be of type object - `BMCServiceDesk__Task__c` instead of having a `list<id>` try to use `list<BMCServiceDesk__Task__c>`

Hope this answers the questions :)